# window.open scrollbar not working

Tags: javascript

I use this commend to open new window

```
 window.open('send_message.html', 'newwindow',  'status=1,width=500,height=500,scrollbars=1');
```

Everything work fine and I see the scroll bar, but I It is not working - it is just standing there...

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: can you show where it is or give screenshot of that

Comment: can't  able to scroll the scrollbars?

Comment: I checked again and i can move down with the arrows but i still want to use the right scroll and it is not moving...

Comment: what browser are you using ?

Comment: chrome.....................

Comment: try scrollbars=yes' and try

Comment: {margin:0;padding:0;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;} try adding this css code in send_message.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45577/discussion-between-karthick-kumar-ganesh-and-user1932595)